# my smtp settings are not working on interspire email marketer

Tags: interspire-shopping-cart

I have setup IEM on justhost. It installed fine. Now when I'm sending emails, it says: `cannot connect to server error 110`

Also I have my doming using google apps emailing server. Have configured it on just host using there google apps wizards.

The settings for IEM are bellow:

```
smtp host: ssl://smtp.gmail.com
smtp user: my email id
smtp pass: my pass
port : 465
```

But it gives the error:
`A test email has not been successfully sent to the email address rohan@skylite.com: Unable to connect to mail server: Connection timed out(110)`

The cname that it changed is:

```
HostRecord       Points to               TTL    
mail             ghs.google.com          14400  
www              mydomain.com            14400
```

MX rec are
the TTL is 14400 and ya just host dosnt make it less

```
1   @   aspmx.l.google.com  14400
5   @   alt1.aspmx.l.google.com 14400   
5   @   alt2.aspmx.l.google.com 14400
10  @   aspmx2.googlemail.com   14400
10  @   aspmx3.googlemail.com   14400
```

So guys, what's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your server's outbound port 465 may be closed, causing the error. You should use the portcheck.php script to test your ports. Refer to the interspire documentation:
https://www.interspire.com/support/kb/questions/1208/How+do+I+use+Amazon+SES+with+Interspire+Email+Marketer%3F

Answer (score 0):

Forget using Gmail with Justhost.com they block 465 587 SMTP ports. It is really really really annoying. You have to send emails using PHP sendmail which end up 60% of the time getting treated as spam!

Comment: Just host have this article https://my.justhost.com/cgi/help/206. Pretty much unless you use an email address that is on their server eg you are not using gmail as your mx records you are going to run into all sorts of issues. But then if you uses a shared server to send emails from you are going to run into being treated like a spammer so you can't win.